# Surprise: MethodInfor Invoke faster than direct call?

Tags: c#, reflection, methodinfo

I need to invoke a generic method by `MethodInfo.Invoke`, because I only have generic type at runtime. I heard about MethodInfo.Invoke performance issue, that it's a lot slower than call method directly. So, to test about performance, I created benchmark program:

```
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Benmarking
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<BenchmarkTest>();
        }
    }

    public class BenchmarkTest
    {
        private const int _count = 1000000;
        private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Type> _typesResult = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Type>();
        private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, MethodInfo> _methodsInfo = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, MethodInfo>();

        [Benchmark]
        public async Task<object> InvokeCastGenericCall()
        {
            return await ((dynamic)new Test()).GetList(new Respone<object>(), _count).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public async Task<object> DirectCall()
        {
            return await new Test().GetList(new Respone<object>(), _count).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public async Task<object> InvokeMethodCall()
        {
            var typeResult = typeof(object);

            var methodInfo = typeof(Test).GetMethod(nameof(Test.GetList)).MakeGenericMethod(typeResult);

            Task task = (Task)methodInfo.Invoke(new Test(), new object[] { new Respone<object>(), _count });

            await task.ConfigureAwait(false);

            return ((dynamic)task).Result;
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public async Task<object> InvokeMethodCall_Cache()
        {
            var typeResult = _typesResult.GetOrAdd(typeof(object), type => typeof(object));

            var methodInfo = _methodsInfo.GetOrAdd(typeResult, type => typeof(Test).GetMethod(nameof(Test.GetList)).MakeGenericMethod(type));

            Task task = (Task)methodInfo.Invoke(new Test(), new object[] { new Respone<object>(), _count });

            await task.ConfigureAwait(false);

            return ((dynamic)task).Result;
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public async Task<List<T>> GetList<T>(Respone<T> input, int count) where T : class, new()
        {
            IEnumerable<T> Get()
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    yield return new T();
            }

            return await Task.FromResult(Get().ToList());
        }
    }

    public class Respone<T> where T : new()
    {

    }
}
```

The results were strange, MethodInfo.Invoke even faster than call method directly. And the fastest is cast object to dynamic and call dynamic method.
The result is present in below image:
[image]

I was worried about where I made the wrong benchmark? Can anyone explain it to me? Thank you very much!

Comment: The question is wich *actuall* MSIL code the Compilers makes from your Source Code. And how it is run by the Framework. Between Compiler Optimsaitions, the JiT Compiler and dead code detection, you might end up with something very diffferent from what you expect.

Comment: @Christopher I don't really understand what you mean, I'm using netcore 3.1

Comment: Any differences in the method invocation style should be in the sub 1ms range, so I'm not sure what difference you're measuring there, perhaps GC.  In any case if your method takes 100ms to run, it's not going to matter how you invoke it.

Comment: What Browne said. Also, read the Speed Rant: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft In fact, my method can call DbContext to get data from the database. In benchmark program, I just only create a method fake data.Initially I used MethodInfo.Invoke, then, I thought of the solution cast into dynamic object to call my method, but worried about the performance, so I tried the benchmark, and surprisingly, cast to dynamic was even faster than calling the method directly